# Minimal-change algorithm which maximises 'swapping'

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics

This is a question on combinatorics from a non-mathematician, so please try to bear with me!

Given an array of n distinct characters, I want to generate subsets of k characters in a minimal-change order, i.e. an order in which generation i+1 contains exactly one character that was not in generation i. That's not too hard in itself. However, I also want to maximise the number of cases in which the character that is swapped **out** in generation i+1 is the same character that was swapped **in** in generation i. To illustrate, for n=7, k=3:

abc  abd  abe* abf* abg* afg  aeg* adg* acg* acd  ace* acf* aef  adf* ade
bde  bdf  bef  bcf* bce  bcd* bcg* bdg  beg* bfg* cfg  ceg* cdg* cde  cdf* cef  def  deg  dfg  efg

The asterisked strings indicate the case I want to maximise; e.g. the e that is new in generation 3, abe, replaces a d that was new in generation 2, abd. It doesn't seem possible to have this happen in every generation, but I want it to happen as often as possible.

Typical array sizes that I use are 20-30 and subset sizes around 5-8.

I'm using an odd language, [Icon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icon_programming_language) (or actually its derivative [Unicon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicon_(programming_language))), so I don't expect anyone to post code that I can used directly. But I will be grateful for answers or hints in pseudo-code, and will do my best to translate C etc. Also, I have noticed that problems of this kind are often discussed in terms of arrays of integers, and I can certainly apply solutions posted in such terms to my own problem.

Thanks

Kim Bastin

Edit 15 June 2010:

I do seem to have got into deeper water than I thought, and while I'm grateful for all answers, not all of them have been relevant. As an example of a solution which is NOT adequate, let me post my own Unicon procedure for generating k-ary subsets of a character set s in a minimal change order. Things you need to know to understand the code are: a preposed * means the size of a structure, so if s is a string, *s means the size of s (the number of characters it contains). || is a string concatenation operation. A preposed ! produces each element of a structure, e.g. each character of a string, in turn on successive passes. And the 'suspend' control structure returns a result from a procedure, but leaves the procedure 'in suspense', with all local variables in place, so that new results can be produced if the procedure is called in a loop.

```
procedure revdoor(s, k)  
# Produces all k-subsets of a string or character set s in a 'revolving  
# door' order. Each column except the first traverses the characters  
# available to it in alphabetical and reverse alphabetical order  
# alternately. The order of the input string is preserved. 
# If called in a loop as revdoor("abcdefg", 3), 
# the order of production is: abc, abd, abe, abf, abg, acg, acf, ace, acd,  
# ade, adf, adg, aeg, aef, afg, bfg, bef, beg, bdg, bdf, bde, bcd, bce,  
# bcf, bcg, cdg, cdf, cde, cef, ceg, cfg, dfg, deg, def, efg  

local i  
static Ctl  

if /Ctl then {             # this means 'if Ctl doesn't exist'
  if k = 0 then return ""  
  Ctl := list(k, 1)        # a list of k elements, each initialised to 1.
}  

if Ctl[k] = 1 then {  
  if k = 1 then suspend !s else  
    every i := 1 to *s-k+1 do {  
      suspend s[i] || revdoor(s[i+1:0], k-1)  
    }   
  } else {  
    if k = 1 then suspend !reverse(s) else  
    every i := -k to -*s by -1 do {  
      suspend s[i] || revdoor(s[i+1:0], k-1)  
    }  
  }  

  # the following line multiplies element k of Ctl by -1 if k < size of Ctl
  # (this controls the order of generation of characters), 
  # and destroys Ctl on final exit from the procedure.
  if k < *Ctl then Ctl[k] *:= -1 else Ctl := &null   

end
```

Note that the output of the above procedure is not optimal in my sense. One result of my investigations so far is that the maximum 'swapping score' for a list of k-ary subsets of n elements is not less than comb(n-1, k), or in the case of n=7, k=3, the maximum score is at least comb(6, 3) = 20. I define the 'swapping score' of a list as the number of items in the list whose new element replaces an element in the previous item which was itself new. I haven't got the mathematical equipment to prove this, but it is easy to see with k=1 or k=2. For certain (n,k) a slightly higher score is possible, as in the case of n=7, k=3:

abc abd abe abf abg
acg adg aeg afg
efg dfg cfg bfg
beg bdg bcg
bcd bce bcf
bdf bef
def cef aef
adf acf
acd ace
ade
bde cde
cdf cdg
ceg
deg (swapping score = 21)

It may be noted that the above list is in 'strong minimal change order' (like word golf: the new character is always in the same position as the character it replaces), which may indicate the direction my own work is taking. I hope to post something more in a few days.

Kim

Comment: I've had the privilege of working with Icon once; it's an awesome language. `if a < b < c`, `if y < (x | 5)`, etc.

Comment: You use the letter "n" both in "n distinct characters" and in "generation n". I suggest using "generation i" instead.

Comment: I've seen a similar algorithm once while working in a machine translation project. Just a try to help your search. I was not deeply involved with that algs (I remember that the name had the word "tiling" in it)

Comment: I love this question.  I've spent more time thinking about (and failing to answer!) this question than any other so far.  But I can say that you are getting into very deep stuff here: you may have better luck on MathOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly straightforward. In order to maximise replacement just think of the characters as numbers and increment the string by one till you have reached the upper limit.
Then check to see that you don't use the same character twice in the string.
I think this would work:

```
char c[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};
const int n = 5;
const int k = 3;
char s[k];

void print()
{
    for( int i = 0; i < k; ++i )
        putchar(c[s[i]]);
    putchar('\n');
}

bool increment( int m )
{
    // reached the limit?
    if( ++s[m] == n && m == 0 )
        return false;

    next:   
    for( int i = 0; i < m; ++i )
    {
        if( s[m] == n )
        {
            // carry
            s[m] = 0;
            if( !increment( m-1 ))
                return false;
            goto next;
        }
        else if( s[i] == s[m] )
        {
            // the character is already used
            ++s[m];
            goto next;
        }   
    }
    return true;
}

int main(int, char**)
{   
    // initialise
    for( int i = 0; i < k; ++i )
        s[i] = i;

    // enumerate all combinations
    do
        print();
    while(increment(k-1));
}
```

Comment: As far as I can understand this C (tracing it with pen and paper — I couldn't get it to compile under LCC-win32), its first few results are: abc abd abe acb... 

If I'm right, this is not what I want, and it seems I haven't formulated the problem completely. I want to produce all k-ary <b>combinations</b>, not permutations, of n characters. See my example for n=7, k=3. acb is a permutation of abc, so should not be produced if abc has been produced previously.

Kim Bastin

Answer (score 0):

Kim, your problem description sounds very much like a (homework) attempt to describe the simplest solution for enumerating all k-combinations of a set of n elements - without giving the actual solution away too easily. Anyway, see below for my shot. I used Java but the important parts are not different from C.

```
public class Homework
{
  /**
   * Prints all k-combinations of a set of n elements. Answer to this 
   * question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698551
   */
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Combinations combinations = new Combinations(7, 3);
    System.out.printf(
        "Printing all %d %d-combinations of a set with %d elements:\n", 
        combinations.size(), combinations.k, combinations.n);
    for (int[] c : combinations)
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(c));
  }

  /**
   * Provides an iterator for all k-combinations of a set of n elements. 
   */
  static class Combinations implements Iterable<int[]>  
  {
    public final int n, k;

    public Combinations(int n, int k)
    {
      if (n < 1 || n < k)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
      this.n = n;
      this.k = k;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<int[]> iterator()
    {
      return new Iterator<int[]>()
      {
        private int[] c;

        @Override
        public void remove() { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }

        @Override
        public int[] next()
        {
          if (c == null)
          {
            c = new int[k];
            for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
              c[i] = i;
          }
          else
          {
            int i = c.length - 1;
            while (i >= 0 && c[i] == n - k + i)
              i--;

            if (i < 0)
              throw new NoSuchElementException();

            c[i]++;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < c.length; j++)
              c[j] = c[i] + j - i;
          }
          return c.clone(); // remove defensive copy if performance is more important
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() { return c == null || c[0] < n - k; }
      };
    }

    /**
     * Returns number of combinations: n! / (k! * (n - k)!).
     */
    public BigInteger size()
    {
      BigInteger s = BigInteger.valueOf(n);
      for (int i = n - 1; i > n - k; i--)
        s = s.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
      for (int i = k; i > 1; i--)
        s = s.divide(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
      return s;
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the output for your example:

```
Printing all 35 3-combinations of a set with 7 elements:
[0, 1, 2] [0, 1, 3] [0, 1, 4] [0, 1, 5] [0, 1, 6] [0, 2, 3] [0, 2, 4] [0, 2, 5] [0, 2, 6] [0, 3, 4] 
[0, 3, 5] [0, 3, 6] [0, 4, 5] [0, 4, 6] [0, 5, 6] [1, 2, 3] [1, 2, 4] [1, 2, 5] [1, 2, 6] [1, 3, 4] 
[1, 3, 5] [1, 3, 6] [1, 4, 5] [1, 4, 6] [1, 5, 6] [2, 3, 4] [2, 3, 5] [2, 3, 6] [2, 4, 5] [2, 4, 6] 
[2, 5, 6] [3, 4, 5] [3, 4, 6] [3, 5, 6] [4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately you do not appear to have read my question with sufficient care. I want to generate k-out-of-n combinations in a minimal-change order, i.e. each new generation should change exactly one character. There are well-known algorithms with this property, but your solution does not exhibit it: note the transition [0,1,6] [0,2,3], which changes two elements. The specific requirement in my question — to maximise the immediate replacement of new elements — is not addressed at all.

Comment: You are right, I should have paid more attention to your minimal-change maximal-swapping requirement. I did not know about minimal-change algorithms (a brief web search proved their existance but I did not see any code without ACM membership etc). Mostly replacing the last elements seems to guarantee a high swap rate for those - but other orderings may maximize that.
If the number of combinations is manageable I am sure that at least some linear programming approach can optimize the combination order as desired. A direct solution is preferable, of course.
May I ask why you need this?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than start with an algorithm, I've tried to think of a way to find a form for the maximum "swapping score", so that you know what to shoot for.  Often an algorithm for producing the desired structure can emerge from such a proof.

It's been a long time since university, but I've tried to think of a combinatorial model that will help to figure this out, without very much luck.

I started by imagining the set of combinations as vertices in a graph, with a edges corresponding to the "adjacency" (only one element difference) of the combinations.  So:

- "n choose k" vertices
- each vertex has degree k(n-k)
- number of edges = "n choose k" * k(n-k) / 2 = "n choose 2" * "n-2 choose k-1"

There's a lot of symmetry to these graphs.  The graph is the same for any given {n,k} as it is for {n,n-k}.  If k=1 or k=n-1 it's the complete graph on n vertices (each combinations differs from all the others by only one character).  I can't see an obvious algorithm from this, though.

Edit: My next thought was to conceive the graph with a slightly different interpretation.  You can think of each {n,k}-combination as a sequence of n bits where there are k 1s.  The position of the 1s corresponds to which of the n characters is present in the combination.  So for n=7 k=3, abc is 1110000, adg is 1001001, efg is 0000111.  With this you can also imagine the points lying at the corners of an n-dimensional hypercube.  So for a given subsequence, the edges match your "minimal swapping" criteria if they are co-planar: I think of them as "cutting planes" through the hypercube.

You are looking for a Hamiltonian path through this graph of combinations, one that meets your special criteria.

Another way to think of your problem is to minimize the number of times in the sequence that you *do* change which character in the combination is being altered.

Comment: I think an optimised search strategy will be more easily found than an algorithm which produces a maximised-swapping order directly. It's easy to start such an order — see the listing for n=7, k=3 below the code I posted — and easy to see patterns. Continuing to the end is harder, and any pattern is hard to discern. I hope you keep thinking along your lines, which are roughly parallel to mine.

Comment: Thanks for nudging me in the direction of graph theory. I find my problem is equivalent to the minimal clique cover problem, i.e. finding the smallest set of cliques that includes every vertex in the graph... which is an NP-complete problem :(

Answer (score 0):

For a good answer, would computing the list of combinations all at once be acceptable, or do you need to compute them one at a time?  In other words, do you need a function:

```
Combination nextCombo();
```

or would

```
vector<Combination> allCombinations();
```

be acceptable?

If computing the combinations in batch is permissible, it is possible that an iterative-deepening A* search (or just an A* search but I suspect it'd run out of memory) would work.  With an admissible heuristic, A* is guaranteed to give the optimum.  I'm short of time, so I decided to post this partial answer and edit the post if I get time to write code.

A* is a graph search algorithm.  In this case, the nodes are lists of combinations used so far (no duplicates allowed in the list).  My plan was to use a bit-string representation for the nodes.  n=30 would fit into a 32 bit integer.  We can arbitrarily permute any solution so that the first combination begins with 0's and ends in 1's, i.e. 000...1111.  A node with a shorter list is connected to a longer one if the two lists are the same up until the last element and the last element differs only in having one 0'bit flipped to a 1 and one 1 bit flipped to a 0.  The distance between the two is 0 if there was a "swap" and 1 if there was a swap.

A second representation for each combination is a sorted list of the bits that are turned on.  One possible admissible heuristic for this graph is to use this index list.  Each time (in the list of combinations) an index is used at a particular position in the index list, mark it off.  The number of positions with un-used indices - the current last changed index is (I believe) the minimal number of swaps that need to happen.

To illustrate this heuristic, consider the sequence abc abd abe* abf* abg afg from above.  (the letters would be numbers in my treatment, but that is a minor difference).  This sequence (which would be one node in the search-graph) would have the following places marked:

```
 1   2   3
*a      
 b  *b   
 c   c  *c
 d   d  *d
 e   e  *e
    *f  *f
        *g
```

Thus the heuristic would predict that there is at least one swap required (since there are no unmarked elements in position 3 and the current position is 2).

If I get the time, I'll edit this to post code and performance of the algorithm.

---

Re: the NP completeness result (in a comment to Zac Thompson's answer).  The graph on which we are searching for a minimal cost Hamiltonian path has a very special structure.  For example, the normally NP-complete Hamiltonian Path problem can be solved in O(n) time with the "enumerate all combinations" algorithm - with n being the number of nodes in the graph.  This structure makes it possible that, though on a general graph, vertex cover is hard, on your graph it may be polynomial (even linear or quadratic).  Of course, since the graph has a lot of nodes for e.g. n=30, k=8 you may still have a lot of computation ahead of you.

Comment: Thank you. It looks as though we are getting somewhere. 
In reply to your opening question, an answer in either form — subset by subset, or all at once in a list — would be equally acceptable. 
Notwithstanding the apparently discouraging conclusion that the problem in general terms is NP-complete, I have made some progress myself in the last few days. However, I now have to go away on a trip shortly and won't be able to post more on this question until 5 July. Hopefully one or both of us (or someone else) may have cracked the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I worked on this problem in 2010 but failed to find a solution then. A few days ago I had another look at some of my notes from that time and suspected I had been very close to a solution. A few minutes later I had the key.

To recapitalute: the requirement is a strict minimal change ordering of the k-subsets of a string s such that LIFO (last in first out) is maximised. I refer to this as maximised ‘swapping’ in earlier posts.

I call the algorithm maxlifo (maximised LIFO) after the key requirement. It takes two parameters, a string s, which must not contain duplicated characters, and a positive integer k not greater than the size of s. The algorithm is recursive, i.e. maxlifo(s, k) uses the output of maxlifo(s, k-1) down to k=1. Output is returned as a list.

Below I give an informal explanation, with examples, using the string "abcdefg" and various values of k. This is followed by an example of implementation as a Unicon procedure. (I’m not fluent in any of the more commonly used languages.)

The case k=1 is trivial — it returns the elements of s in order from first to last.

For k>1, apply the following rules to the output of maxlifo(s, k-1):

(1) For each element of the output of maxlifo(s, k-1), list in a row the k-subsets built from that element with each missing character of s in turn. The order of characters in the subsets is as in s.

(2) Working from the second row down, substitute blank ‘placeholders’ for all occurrences of subsets that appear in an earlier row. Each k-subset of s now appears just once.

(3) In each non-blank row, mark with an initial ! each subset such that there is a placeholder at the same position in the next row. This marking means ‘first’. Exactly one subset will be so marked in each non-blank row.

(4) Delete all rows that are completely blank (contain only placeholders).

(5) In each remaining row except the last, mark with a final ! the subset in the position corresponding to the subset marked ‘first’ in the next lower row. This marking means ‘last’.

Now we can list the final maxlifo ordering of the subsets. Each row from top to bottom is ordered and its elements added in that order to the output list.

(6) In each row from the top down:

(6.1) Remove all blank placeholders.

(6.2) Add to the output list the subset marked ‘first’ (initial !) and remove it from the row.

(6.3) If there are still subsets remaining in the row, either the leftmost or the rightmost subset will be marked ‘last’ (final !). If the rightmost subset is marked ‘last’, add the subsets to the output list in order from left to right, otherwise in order from right to left.

(7) After processing all rows, return the output list.

Example using maxlifo("abcdefg", 2):

Col1 contains the output of maxlifo("abcdefg", 1). The rows of Col2 contain the cliques formed with the remaining characters of s:

```
Col1    Col2
----    ----------------------------
a       ab   ac   ad   ae   af   ag
b       ab   bc   bd   be   bf   bg
c       ac   bc   cd   ce   cf   cg
d       ad   bd   cd   de   df   dg
e       ae   be   ce   de   ef   eg
f       af   bf   cf   df   ef   fg
g       ag   bg   cg   dg   eg   fg
```

Blank out subsets that appear in an earlier row:

```
a       ab   ac   ad   ae   af   ag
b            bc   bd   be   bf   bg
c                 cd   ce   cf   cg
d                      de   df   dg
e                           ef   eg
f                                fg
g
```

Mark the ‘first’ subset in each row (the one with a blank below it):

```
a      !ab   ac   ad   ae   af   ag
b           !bc   bd   be   bf   bg
c                !cd   ce   cf   cg
d                     !de   df   dg
e                          !ef   eg
f                               !fg
g
```

Delete all completely blank rows (only one in this case):

```
a      !ab   ac   ad   ae   af   ag
b           !bc   bd   be   bf   bg
c                !cd   ce   cf   cg
d                     !de   df   dg
e                          !ef   eg
f                               !fg
```

Mark the ’last’ subset in each row (the one with a ‘first’ subset below it).

```
a      !ab   ac!  ad   ae   af   ag
b           !bc   bd!  be   bf   bg
c                !cd   ce!  cf   cg
d                     !de   df!  dg
e                          !ef   eg!
f                               !fg
```

Output each row in the order described above: ‘first’, unmarked, ’last’:

```
                                               Ordered rows:
a      !ab   ac!  ad   ae   af   ag            ab ag af ae ad ac
b           !bc   bd!  be   bf   bg            bc bg bf be bd
c                !cd   ce!  cf   cg            cd cg cf ce
d                     !de   df!  dg            de dg df
e                          !ef   eg!           ef eg
f                               !fg            fg
```

Output: [ab ag af ae ad ac bc bg bf be bd cd cg cf ce df dg de ef eg fg]

Examples for 3 <= k <= 6 are given in less detail. The blank rows deleted in step 4 are left in place.

maxlifo("abcdefg", 3):

```
                                                       Ordered rows:
ab     !abc   abd   abe   abf   abg!                   abc abd abe abf abg
ag            acg   adg   aeg! !afg                    afg acg adg aeg
af            acf   adf! !aef                          aef acf adf
ae            ace! !ade                                ade ace
ad           !acd!                                     acd
ac                     
bc           !bcd   bce   bcf   bcg!                   bcd bce bcf bcg
bg                  bdg   beg! !bfg                    bfg bdg beg
bf                  bdf! !bef                          bef bdf
be                 !bde!                               bde 
bd                                  
cd                 !cde   cdf   cdg!                   cde cdf cdg
cg                        ceg! !cfg                    cfg ceg
cf                       !cef!                         cef
ce                             
de                       !def   deg!                   def deg
dg                             !dfg!                   dfg
df                             
ef                             !efg                    efg
eg                       
fg
```

Output: [abc abd abe abf abg afg acg adg aeg aef acf adf ade ace acd
    bcd bce bcf bcg bfg bdg beg bef bdf bde 
    cde cdf cdg cfg ceg cef 
    def deg dfg 
    efg]

maxlifo("abcdefg", 4):

```
                                            Ordered rows:
abc         !abcd  abce!  abcf   abcg       abcd abcg abcf abce
abd               !abde   abdf!  abdg       abde abdg abdf
abe                      !abef   abeg!      abef abeg
abf                             !abfg!      abfg
abg                                   
afg                acfg!  adfg  !aefg       aefg adfg acfg
acg               !acdg   aceg!             acdg aceg
adg                      !adeg!             adeg
aeg                                  
aef                acef! !adef              adef acef
acf               !acdf!                    acdf
adf                                  
ade               !acde!                    acde
ace                                   
acd                                   
bcd               !bcde   bcdf!  bcdg       bcde bcdg bcdf
bce                      !bcef   bceg!      bcef bceg
bcf                             !bcfg!      bcfg
bcg                                  
bfg                       bdfg! !befg       befg bdfg
bdg                      !bdeg!             bdeg
beg                                  
bef                      !bdef!             bdef
bdf                                  
bde                                  
cde                      !cdef   cdeg!      cdef cdeg
cdf                             !cdfg!      cdfg
cdg                                   
cfg                             !cefg!      cefg
ceg                                  
cef                                  
def                             !defg       defg
deg                          
dfg                          
efg
```

Output: [abcd abcg abcf abce abde abdg abdf abef abeg abfg aefg adfg acfg acdg aceg adeg adef acef acdf acde 
    bcde bcdg bcdf bcef bceg bcfg befg bdfg bdeg bdef 
    cdef cdeg cdfg cefg 
    defg]

maxlifo("abcdefg", 5):

```
                                            Ordered rows:
abcd       !abcde   abcdf   abcdg!          abcde abcdf abcdg 
abcg                abceg! !abcfg           abcfg abceg 
abcf               !abcef!                  abcef 
abce                                
abde               !abdef   abdeg!          abdef abdeg 
abdg                       !abdfg!          abdfg 
abdf                         
abef                       !abefg!          abefg 
abeg                         
abfg                         
aefg                acefg! !adefg           adefg acefg 
adfg               !acdfg!                  acdfg 
acfg                         
acdg               !acdeg!                  acdeg 
aceg                         
adeg                         
adef               !acdef!                  acdef 
acef                         
acdf                         
acde                         
bcde               !bcdef   bcdeg!          bcdef bcdeg 
bcdg                       !bcdfg!          bcdfg 
bcdf                         
bcef                       !bcefg!          bcefg 
bceg                         
bcfg                         
befg                       !bdefg!          bdefg 
bdfg                         
bdeg                         
bdef                         
cdef                       !cdefg           cdefg 
cdeg                         
cdfg                         
cefg                         
defg
```

Output: [abcde abcdf abcdg abcfg abceg abcef abdef abdeg abdfg abefg adefg acefg acdfg acdeg acdef 
    bcdef bcdeg bcdfg bcefg bdefg 
    cdefg]

maxlifo("abcdefg", 6):

```
                                            Ordered rows:
abcde               !abcdef   abcdeg!       abcdef abcdeg 
abcdf                        !abcdfg!       abcdfg 
abcdg                               
abcfg                        !abcefg!       abcefg 
abceg                              
abcef                               
abdef                        !abdefg!       abdefg 
abdeg                               
abdfg                               
abefg                               
adefg                               
acefg                        !acdefg!       acdefg 
acdfg                               
acdeg                               
acdef                               
bcdef                        !bcdefg        bcdefg 
bcdeg                               
bcdfg                               
bcefg                               
bdefg                               
cdefg
```

Output: [abcdef abcdeg abcdfg abcefg abdefg acdefg bcdefg]

Unicon implementation:

```
procedure maxlifo(s:string, k:integer)
# A solution to my combinatorics problem from 2010.
# Return a list of the k subsets of the characters of a string s
# in a minimal change order such that last-in first-out is maximised.
# String s must not contain duplicate characters and in the present 
# implementation must not contain "!", which is used as a marker.

  local ch, cand, Hit, inps, i, j, K, L, Outp, R, S

  # Errors
  if *cset(s) ~= *s then 
    stop("Duplicate characters in set in maxlifo(", s, ", ", k, ")")
  if find("!", s) then 
    stop("Illegal character in set in maxlifo(", s, ", ", k, ")")
  if k > *s then 
    stop("Subset size larger than set size in maxlifo(", s, ", ", k, ")")

  # Special cases
  if k = 0 then return []
  if k = *s then return [s]

  Outp := []
  if k = 1 then {
    every put(Outp, !s)
    return Outp
  }

  # Default case
  S := set()
  K := []

  # Build cliques from output of maxlifo(s, k-1) with the remaining 
  # characters in s, substituting empty strings as placeholders for 
  # subsets already listed.
  every inps := !maxlifo(s, k-1) do { 
    R := []
    every ch := !s do
      if not find(ch, inps) then {
        cand := reorder(inps ++ ch, s)
        if member(S, cand) then cand := "" else insert(S, cand)
        put(R, cand)
      }
    put(K, R)
  }

  # Mark ‘first’ subset in each row with initial "!"
  every i := 1 to *K - 1 do {
    every j := 1 to *K[i] do
      if K[i, j] ~== "" & K[i+1, j] == "" then {
        K[i, j] := "!" || K[i, j]
        break
      }
  }

  # Remove rows containing only placeholders
  every i := *K to 1 by -1 do {
    every if !K[i] ~== "" then break next
    delete(K, i)  
  }

  # Mark ‘last’ subset in each row with final "!"
  every i := 1 to *K - 1 do 
    every j := 1 to *K[i] do 
      if K[i+1, j][1] == "!" then {
        K[i, j] ||:= "!"
        break
      }

  # Build output list
  every R := !K do {

    # Delete placeholders from row (no longer needed and in the way)
    every j := *R to 1 by -1 do if R[j] == "" then delete(R, j)

    # Handle ‘first’ subset and remove from row
    # N.B. ‘First’ subset will be leftmost or rightmost in row
    if R[1][1] == "!" then 
      put(Outp, trim(get(R), '!', 0)) 
      else put(Outp, trim(pull(R), '!', 0))   

    # Handle any remaining subsets, ‘last’ subset last, stripping '!' markers
    # N.B. ‘Last’ subset will be leftmost or rightmost in row after removal
    # of ‘first’ subset.
    if R[-1][-1] == "!" then while put(Outp, trim(get(R), '!', 0)) else
      while put(Outp, trim(pull(R), '!', 0))
  }

  return Outp

end


procedure reorder(cs:cset, s:string)
# Reorder cset cs according to string s

  local r
  # If no s, return set in alphabetical order
  if /s then return string(cs)

  r := ""
  s ? while tab(upto(cs)) do r ||:= move(1)
  return r

end
```